# Dynamic replacement of Latin letters to Cyrillic letters as they're typed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build this program which needs the input part to be similar to google-translate's. that is, Latin letters are dynamically replaced into Cyrillic letters as they're typed (like, when letter B is keyed, the letter Б is printed in the input box and so on)

I tried linking the latin letters to cyrillic letters through onkeyup events, but some letters like Sh(Ш) or Ya(Я) are associated to key-combinations and I can't find a way around it. I'd include the code sample I had already tried out but the problem I have is more of a plan related one than implement related one. It'd be great if I can get help to figure out how to tackle and build this.

TIA

Comment: instead of looking at a key pressed.. look at all the text in the input and replace with either `split` logic or `regex`.. if you don't give me an example I can't tell u further ;-;

Comment: @TheBombSquad https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/russian.htm is pretty much what I'm aiming for haha, I don't think I can explain it as good

Comment: I made an example.. it was fun to do :D

Comment: Go to https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/russian.htm, press F12, click "sources" tab and on the left you can see the code doing all of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm bored so I coded up an example(proof of concept)

I keep determine what the normal text is, and what the converted text is, and that is what allows multiple key combinations(looking at the *entire* string not just per key input)

```js
var _change={sh:'lol',ab:'cd',a:'z',SH:'LOL',AB:'CD',A:'Z'} //largest strings first
var _default={lol:'sh',cd:'ab',z:'a',LOL:'SH',CD:'AB',Z:'A'} //largest strings first
//you can fill these objects with as many translations as you want
//if a smaller string was first, "ab" would turn to "zb" before it can turn into "cd"
//make sure the every translation text is different from any original text
var _text=document.getElementById('text')
let defaultText=(text)=>text.split('').map(l=>_default[l]||l).join('')
let changeText=(text)=>{
  Object.keys(_change).forEach(toSplit=>text=text.split(toSplit).join(_change[toSplit]))
  return text
}
setInterval(()=>{
  let text=_text.value
  _text.value=changeText(defaultText(text))
},300)
```

```html
<input id="text" />
<p>I only have 3(technically 6) examples.. <i>'sh' to 'lol'</i>, <i>'a' to 'z'</i> and <i>'ab' to 'cd'</i>
<br><p>technically 6 because I also have <i>'SH' to 'LOL'</i> and so forth
```

Comment: oh wow thanks mate exactly what I wanted, appreciate it :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
const map = {
  'b': 'Б', //...etc
}

function onPressHandler(e) {
  const value = e.target.value 
  //alternatively you could handle each pressed key at a time

  const length = value.length
  let output = ''

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)
    output += map[value.chatAt(i)]

  e.target.value = output // if you want or just return it


}
```